# Блокировка за спам при расслылке уведомлений в каталоге

Tags: спам

Купил [скрипт каталога организаций и фирм](https://www.plati.market/itm/skript-katalog-organizacij-firm-i-soft-bizness/360973?ai=144023), залил более 2 млн предприятий. Во время активации каждой организации уходило уведомление. 
В итоге хостер весь сайт за спам вырубил. Пошел к другому. Тот и вовсе отключил весь аккаунт.
Где можно найти нормального хостера, который не блочит за рассылку? Или может есть какие-то другие обходные пути?
К слову рассылка еще и к тому же попадает в спам, даже когда доходит. Это тоже не желательно. 
В общем жду любого дельного совета по данному вопросу.

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы вам тут помогли рассылать спам? это не приветствуется

Comment: Дельный совет — прекратите рассылку. Вы спамер.

Comment: В общем ребят, попробовал я еще несколько хостеров. Надо сказать ситуация аналогичная. Пробовал настроить почтовый ящик со своим доменом у них, но надо признать техподдержка у них оставляет желать лучшего. 

Остановился на http://wazzup.su, там и почта не блокируется на KVM тарифах, и техподдерка быстро реагирует и помогает решать любые проблемы.

Comment: Подскажите, а как бы мне теперь проверить почту на работоспособность. Получается, что сейчас я отправляю сообщения себе на yandex, gmail и mail.ru. Туда сообщения доходят. Но ведь много еще и других ящиков. Можно как-то отправить с сервера запрос и получить ответ. Типа почтовый ящик не работает, или в спам попал. И на php его обработать уже и куда-нибудь занести скажем в базу. И потом бы я уже мог посмотреть все недоставленные письма и проанализировать, что как и почему. 
Буду крайне признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Вы рассылаете 2 млн писем одного и того-же содержания на адреса которые вам никогда не писали, это есть спам.
Любой нормальный хостер будет вас банить за спам, + вы попадете в черный список по ip.
минимум вам нужно сделать почти каждое письмо уникальным, отправлять письма небольшими порциями, и сделать ящик который будет вызывать доверие. 
Но опять же как только 100-200 чел пометят ваше письмо как спам, фильтр автоматически дальше будет направлять вас в спам.